# Displaying the error message from web service in jquery validation custom method

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm adding a custom method to jquery validation that calls a webservice, but the web service returns more then just a boolean. Is it possible to show the error based on return call of the web service. e.g. say I want an email address to be valid & not in use, so my web service checks this an returns 0 - ok, 1 - not valid, 2 - in use. How can I get jquery to show to correct error message based in the response ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this links for reference,if u are using asp.net(c#)

[jQuery Remote Validation with ASP.Net Webservices](https://web.archive.org/web/20130904224626/http://craftycoders.com/post/2009/04/13/jQuery-Remote-Validation-with-ASPnet-Webservices.aspx)

[The power of CustomValidator - Validate with WebServices](https://web.archive.org/web/20130723025025/http://www.codegolem.com:80/post/The-power-of-CustomValidator-Validate-with-WebServices.aspx)

[Check Existing Values with ASP.NET CustomValidator + jQuery $.ajax()](https://web.archive.org/web/20190725163605/http://brian.dobberteen.com:80/code/jquery_ajax_custom_validator/)

[ASP.NET MVC Client-Side Validation Summary with jQuery Validation Plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025164158/http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/27/asp.net-mvc-client-side-validation-summary-with-jquery-validation-plugin.aspx)